# How can i get search string with space using JSON?

Tags: apex, api, json

I have created a class using API end point URL, While getting its response we are able to observe blank spaces in the output string which should not be present.

Please help me out with a solution.
Please find the attached screenshot for reference.
[image]

Comment: You need to do url encode to remove this (line no 38)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to Encode the URL with `EncodingUtil.urlEncode` as below. Hope this will help.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
Http http = new Http();

String endpoint = 'http://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search?q='+ EncodingUtil.urlEncode('41,Boulevard de strasbourg','UTF-8');
req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
req.setMethod('GET');

try {
    res = http.send(req);
    System.debug('######'+res.getBody());
} catch(System.CalloutException e) {
    System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
    System.debug(res.toString());
}
```